# how to rotate icon arrow in jquery show hide toggle?

Tags: jquery, toggle, hide, show

there..

---

I want to ask you?
how to rotate the arrow icon in jquery show hide toggle?
I've tried it here: http://jsfiddle.net/mikonimations/EzQsG/

```
<section id="evenmorelinks"><h1><div class="arrow before"></div><a id="show-title" onclick="false">Show More</a><div class="arrow after"></div></h1></section>

<div id="cnt" style="display: none" class="fcolcontainer2">
<div class="f2segment"><h2>Example block</h2><span><a>333</a></span></div>
<div class="f2segment"><h2>Example block</h2><span><a>333</a></span></div>
<div class="f2segment"><h2>Example block</h2><span><a>333</a></span></div>
<div class="f2segment"><h2>Example block</h2><span><a>333</a></span></div>
<div class="f2segment"><h2>Example block</h2><span><a>333</a></span></div>
<div class="f2segment"><h2>Finish block</h2><span><a>333</a></span></div>
```

This Jquery

```
 (function ($) {
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#show-title").click(function () {
         if ($('#cnt').is(":visible")) {
             $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/Hide/, 'Show'));
         } else {
             $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/Show/, 'Hide'));
         }
         // Do it afterwards as the operation is async
         $("#cnt").slideToggle("fast");
      });
  });
```

but have not been successful.
Please help me!
Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of stuff going on in there, but if I read your intention it boils down to adding expanded class to one of the parent elements. Try this:

```
$("#show-title").click(function () {
    $(this).parents('#evenmorelinks').toggleClass('expanded');
    // Do it afterwards as the operation is async
    $("#cnt").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/cuUfK/).

Comment: ok, this working. 
but there are things that can not work, to show hide and hide show.